# add 2 days to date update query

Tags: mysql, database, date, datetime

I want to create query to Automatic add 2 days to column name (start_time) in format 2020-07-01 07:00 pm i want the new output to be in same format (2020-07-01 07:00 pm)

Comment: What do you mean ‘automatic’?

Answer (score -1):

How about that:

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD("2020-07-01", INTERVAL 2 DAY);
```

Comment: can i replace "2020-07-01" to column name (start_time)

Comment: the problen now the date format changed i want to be the same 2020-07-01 07:00 pm
now conver to 2020-07-02 07:00:00.000000

Comment: select not update the column data , how can i use update